# Mapstruct: how to autowire abstract class mapper

Tags: java, mapstruct

my problem seems easy, but may be I'm doing something wrong. this is mapper class with `@Named("toLocationListCommon")` bean which suppose to be used in other mappers

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public abstract class CommonLocationMapper {
    @Setter(onMethod_ = @Autowired)
    protected TestService testService;

    @Named("toLocationListCommon")
    List<Location> toLocationListCommon(List<? extends ILocation> loc) {
        //do mapping logic
    }

}
```

here I'm trying to use it:

```
@Mapper(implementationName = "V1Impl", config = CommonMapper.CommonMapperConfig.class, uses = CommonLocationMapper.class)
interface TestMapper {
    //other mapping methods
}
```

I expect to have autowired bean `CommonLocationMapper` in implementation for `TestMapper`, but I haven't.
What I'm doing wrong? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

uses clause in @Mapper annotation allow your mapper to use the mappers you defined if they are required. If you want to just get a reference to mapper you can use.

```
MyMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper( MyMapper.class );
```